# Let pets "get near" vs "come close to" you

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which one's correct? E.g. if one's too scared and won't even pat them.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are both correct, you could use either one.

I will write some example sentences for you. All of these are correct and sound natural. There is no particular difference in meaning.

- "She is so scared of dogs that she won't even go near them."
- "He doesn't like horses, and cries if they even come close to him."
- "My daughter was scratched by a cat once, and now she won't let one near her."
- "Every time the neighbor's dog comes close to him, he runs away."